# Omnet++: class not found when called as a submodule of a compound module

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am creating a simple omnet++ simulation. Part of that simulation uses a simple module called a *packet generator*. It will become part of a compound module inside a project called *complete*. However, when I try to use *packetGenerator* in a compound module, I get the following error message when trying to run a simulation:

> Error in module (omnetpp::cModule) net.tx (id=2) during network setup: Class "packetGenerator" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel().

Yes, I went into properties-->project references and referred to the *packetGenerator* project (as seen in the image). I have also called Define_Module(packetGenerator), as seen in **packetGenerator.cc**

I have deduced that the problem occurs in the *submodules* section of the compound module, but I am not sure how to fix this. Any assistance is appreciated. If I omit the inclusion of the *packetGenerator* submodule in the *TransmitterNode* compound module, then the simulation will run fine (and do nothing, since there is no functionality yet).

**packetGenerator.cc** (inside the project *packetGenerator*)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include <AppMessage_m.h>
using namespace omnetpp;

//Simple module responsible for continuously generating AppMessage messages
class packetGenerator: public cSimpleModule {

  private:
    cMessage* event;
    int seqno;
    int senderId;

  public:
    packetGenerator();
    virtual ~packetGenerator();

  protected:

    virtual void initialize() override;

    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;

    virtual AppMessage* generateMessage();
};

Define_Module(packetGenerator);

packetGenerator::packetGenerator() {
    event = nullptr;
    seqno = 0;
}

packetGenerator::~packetGenerator() {
    cancelAndDelete(event);
}

void packetGenerator::initialize() {

    senderId = par("nodeIdentifier");
    event = new cMessage("event");
    scheduleAt(0.0, event);
}

void packetGenerator::handleMessage(cMessage* msg) {

    WATCH(seqno);

    //Go here when the new message is scheduled to be sent (after the delay)
    if (msg == event) {
        send(generateMessage(), "out");
        simtime_t delay = par("iatDistribution");
        scheduleAt(simTime() + delay, event);
    }

    //If we receive a message that isn't our timer-expiry message (e.g. from the MAC), go here
    else {
        AppMessage* appmsg = check_and_cast<AppMessage*>(msg);
        EV << "Message received" << endl;
        EV << "Message kind: " << msg->getKind() << endl;
        delete appmsg;
    }

}

AppMessage* packetGenerator::generateMessage() {


    simtime_t timeStamp = simTime();
    int sequenceNumber = seqno;
    seqno++;
    int msgSize = par("messageSize");

    char messageName[30];
    sprintf(messageName, "Message from %d", senderId);

    AppMessage* msg = new AppMessage(messageName);
    msg->setTimeStamp(timeStamp);
    msg->setSenderId(senderId);
    msg->setSequenceNumber(sequenceNumber);
    msg->setMsgSize(msgSize);

    return msg;
}
```

**net.ned** (inside the project *complete*)

```
package complete;
import packetgenerator.packetGenerator;

module TransmitterNode
{
    parameters:
        int nodeIdentifier; //These need to be unique in the simulation
        double nodeXPosition;
        double nodeYPosition;
        @display("bgb=468,188;i=device/cellphone");
    gates:
    submodules:      
        packetGenerator: packetGenerator {
            @display("p=79,90;i=block/source");
        }
    connections:
}

network net
{
    submodules:
        tx: TransmitterNode;
    connections:
}
```

[image: properties]

Comment: You should build `packetGenerator` to shared library and check the checkbox "Export this shared/static library for other projects".

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project `packetGenerator` has to be built as shared library and checked the checkbox `Export this shared/static library for other projects` in `Project` | `Properties` | `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | selection of root or src directory | `Options...` | `Target`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It has been resolved after finding the package is wrong. Like you are using "package complete", maybe this is creating a problem. You can see in the window of the errors if you found that like "complete.linklayer.**" so maybe the package complete needs to change accordingly mentioned in the errors and suggested actually required package. As per your question, I think, you have same problem. I am just talking about my experience. Let's have a try.